# Need help in running this for Loop

Tags: java

Please be as simple as possible in explanation as I am a beginner.
Receives an integer n and returns the smallest integer that is greater than
    n and in which the sum of the digits is divisible by 11.
For example, nextCRC(100) = 119 because 119 is the first integer greater than
    100 and the sum of its digits 1+1+9 = 11 is divisible by 11.

1) The first thing which i cant understand is that why is there a "true" in the for loop at the start.

2) How do I compute the next number which is larger than and divisible by 11.

3)How do I do this for negative numbers, numbers < 0 .

```
public static int nextCRC(int n)
{
    try
    {
        **for (int i = n + 1; true; i++)**
        {
            String number = String.valueOf(Math.abs(i));

            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < number.length(); j++)
            {
                count += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(number.charAt(j)));
            }

            if (count > 0 && count % 11 == 0) return  i;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(nextCRC(100));
    System.out.println(nextCRC(-100));
}
```

}

Comment: 1) The `true` just means "never break". The expression between the semicolons is evaluated before each loop iteration, and if it's false the loop breaks and execution moves on to whatever comes after the loop. Actually it's unnecessary: `for (int i = n + 1; ; i++)` would do the same.

Comment: 2) You don't need to convert to a string and back to sum the digits. There are plenty of questions on SO (and elsewhere) which show how you can do this better.

Answer (score 0):

I added comments to the code explaining what each part of the code does:

```
public static int nextCRC(int n)
{
try
{
    for (int i = n + 1; true; i++) // the for loop will loop as long as the boolean is true. i starts at the inputted value and increments by 1 each iteration
//Since the value is "true" it will loop forever or until a value is returned
    {
        String number = String.valueOf(Math.abs(i)); // convert the number to string

        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < number.length(); j++) //iterate through each digit in the number
        {
            count += Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(number.charAt(j))); // add the value of each digit to cout variable
        }

        if (count > 0 && count % 11 == 0) return  i; //return the number that was checked if the sum of its digits is divisible by 11
    }
}
catch (Exception e) // return a value of 0 if there is an exception
{
    return 0;
}
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
System.out.println(nextCRC(100));
System.out.println(nextCRC(-100));
}
}
```